# In "truly asynchronous" code that uses async-await, isn't there still SOME "thread" that is stuck waiting?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

Let's say I properly use `async`-`await`, like

```
await client.GetStringAsync("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

I understand that the thread that invokes the `await` becomes "free", that is, something further up the call chain isn't stuck executing some loop equivalent to

```
bool done = false;
string html = null;
for(; !done; done = GetStringIfAvailable(ref html));
```

which is what it would be doing if I called the synchronous version of `GetStringAsync` (probably called `GetString` by convention).

However, here's where I get confused. Even if the calling thread or any other thread in application's pool of available threads isn't blocked with such a loop, then something is, because, as I understand, at a low level there is always polling going on. So, instead of lowering the total amount of work, I'm simply pushing work to something "beneath" my application's threads ... or something like that.

Can someone clear this up for me?

Comment: Stephen Clearly has a great [article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) on this general topic.

Comment: "There is always polling going on." If that were true, your CPU would always be at 100% usage. The OS generally uses signaling rather than polling.

Answer (score 3):

No.

The compiler will convert methods that use `async` / `await` in to state machines that can be broken up in to multiple steps.  Once an `await` is hit, the state of the method is stored and execution is "offloaded" back to the thread that called it.  If the task is waiting on things like disk IO, the OS kernel  will end up relying on physical CPU interrupts to let the kernel know when to signal the application to resume processing.  The state of the pending method is loaded, and queued up on an available thread (the same thread that hit the `await` if `ConfigureAwait` is `true`, or any free thread if `false`) *(This last part isn't exactly right, please see  Scott Chamberlain's comments below.)*.  Think of it like an `event`, where the application asks the hardware to "ping" it once the work is done, while the application gets back to doing whatever it was doing before.

There *are* some cases where a new thread is spun up to do the work, such as `Task.Run` which does the work on a `ThreadPool` thread, but no thread is blocking while awaiting it to complete.

It is important to keep in mind that asynchronous operations using  `async`/ `await`, are all about pausing, storing, retrieving, and resuming that state-machine.  It doesn't really care about what happens inside the `Task`, what happens there, and how it happens, isn't directly related to `async` / `await`.

I was very confused by `async` / `await` too, until I really understood how the method is converted to a state-machine.  Reading up on [exactly what your `async` methods get converted to](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/535635/Async-Await-and-the-Generated-StateMachine) by the compiler might help.

Comment: Just one point I want to clarify: *"queued up on an available thread (the same thread that hit the `await` if `ConfigureAwait` is `true`,..."*, that is not exactly true. if ConfigureAwait is true it will queue up the work using `SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(Action) `. If you have a `SynchronizationContext.Current` (thread pool threads don't), and if that context posts it's requests to the UI thread (asp.net's `AspNetSynchronizationContext ` does not), then the await will run on the UI thread.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Ahh, thank you for clarifying that.  The interaction with the `SyncronizationContext` is something that I wasn't super clear on before.  Knowing how that works suddenly has a lot more things making sense to me.

Comment: Here is a good article that explains it very well https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx

Comment: Can the down-voter please explain what I got wrong so that I can correct it?

Comment: Every answer has a downvote, i think it might of been a rage voting and everyone was clicked.

Comment: Let me upvote to balance the downvoter, and add this: if `ConfigureAwait` is true or not specified, an asynchronous `await`'s continuation will use the current `SynchronizationContext`; if there is none, the current `TaskScheduler`; if there is none, `TaskScheduler.Default`, which runs on the `ThreadPool`.

Answer (score -2):

You're pushing it off onto the operating system--which will run some other thread if it can rather than simply wait.  It only ends up in a busy-wait when it can't find any thread that wants to run.